# Оптимизация кода по поиску чисел в массиве по условию

Tags: python, оптимизация

Условия
Дан массив a длины n, состоящий из чисел от 0 до 106. Требуется отвечать на запросы типа «найдите значение побитового AND всех целых чисел в интервале от l до r включительно».

Напоминаем, что результат побитового AND нескольких чисел — это число, в котором бит равен единице тогда и только тогда, когда во всех этих числах соответствующий бит равен единице.

Система оценки
Всего в задаче 20 тестов (не считая примера). Каждый тест оценивается в 5 баллов.

Гарантируется, что не менее, чем в 30% тестов n,q ≤ 1000 и не менее, чем в 30% тестов ai равны 0 или 1.

Формат входных данных
Первая строка входных данных содержит два целых числа n и q (1 ≤ n ≤ 2·105; 1 ≤ q ≤ 2·105) — количество чисел и количество запросов соответственно.
Вторая строка содержит массив a, перечисленный слева направо, и содержит n целых чисел ai (0 ≤ ai ≤ 106).
Каждая из последующих q строк содержит по два целых числа l и r — границы интервала для очередного запроса (1 ≤ l ≤ r ≤ n).

Формат выходных данных
Для каждого запроса в отдельной строке выведите одно целое число — результат ответа на очередной запрос.

Примеры
Входные данные:

```
5 4
2 5 3 4 1
1 3
4 5
2 5
2 3
```

Выходные данные:

```
0
0
0
1
```

Мой вариант:

```
from operator import __and__
from functools import reduce
 
n, q = map(int, input().split())
*a, = map(int, input().split())
res = []
for _ in range(q):
    left, right = map(int, input().split())
    res.append(reduce(__and__, a[left-1:right]))
print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Comment: А что с Вашим вариантом не так? (Напишите это в вопросе)

Comment: Мне нужно его оптимизировать, чтобы он выполнялся быстрее)

Comment: Я к тому, что вы бы либо тесты предоставили, которые вы не проходите, либо условия его прохождения и текущий результат.

Comment: Ограничение стоит 6 секунд на выполнение кода, а тесты скрыты.

Comment: судя по тому, что в 30% тестов в списке есть 0, наверное, можно вместо reduce сделать цикл и при получении 0 его прерывать, ясно, что результат будет 0

Comment: Можете пожалуйста продемонстрировать, а то я не до конца понимаю о чем вы?)

Comment: Сделать обычный цикл и прерывать его через `break` как только получится `0` ибо дальше бессмысленно продолжать - вот смысл этой оптимизации. В частности в вашем первом примере `2 & 5 == 0`, и дальше можно не считать.

Comment: @Evi , если какой-то из ответов вам помог - поставьте слева от него галочку и при желании проголосуйте за него нажав на стрелку вверх, таким образом Вы сможете отблагодарить автора ответа.

Answer (score 3):

106 это конечно 10<sup>6</sup>. В каждом числе не более 20 бит. Из всех чисел выделим младший бит:

> ```
>   2 5 3 4 1 - числа
>   0 1 1 0 1 - младшие биты
> 0 1 1 1 2 2 - количество нулевых младших битов с начала списка
> ```

По последнему списку можно вычислить будет ли установлен младший бит в ответе на запрос `left`, `right`. Если числа на позициях `left - 1` и `right` равны, то нулей между ними нет, бит надо установить. Иначе его надо сбросить.

Рассуждения повторить для всех двадцати битов. Программа отвечает на любой запрос за 20 операций:

```
def zero_counts(a, bit):
    c = 0
    yield c
    for v in a:
        if v & bit == 0:
            c += 1
        yield c


n, q = map(int, input().split())
a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))

counts = tuple(tuple(zero_counts(a, 1 << k)) for k in range(20))

for _ in range(q):
    left, right = map(int, input().split())
    print(sum(
        1 << k if counts[k][right] == counts[k][left - 1] else 0
        for k in range(20)
    ))
```

Comment: До сих пор по, по времени не проходит(

Comment: В моём варианте перемешаны ввод диапазонов и вывод результатов. В некоторых системах тестирования это приводит к замедлению вывода. Введите диапазоны в массив (как было сделано у вас), затем выдайте ответы.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на тестирующую систему.

Comment: К сожалению нет возможности отправить ссылку, но если вам это поможет, гарантируется, что не менее, чем в 30% тестов n,q ≤ 1000 и не менее, чем в 30% тестов ai равны 0 или 1.

Comment: Попробуйте сами переупорядочить ввод/вывод, напишите сюда комментарий.

Comment: Я тупая, я не понимаю(

Comment: 1. Не унижайте себя, этого тут не любят. 2. Вы видите что у меня в последнем цикле то ввод, то вывод? Разделите последний цикл на два цикла: в первом введите все запросы. Во втором вычислите и напечатайте все ответы.

Answer (score 1):

можно

1. самому в цикле вычислять `and`:

   ```
    res &= value
   ```
2. на каждом шаге проверять равен ли результат 0 и если равен - прервать цикл, поскольку уже 0 никак не изменится